# Same file displays UTF-8 chars differently on two servers

Tags: php, utf-8

Cleaning up behind an intern here: This include file with French text displays accented UTF-8 characters correctly on my testbed server

http://www.surreydata.dreamhosters.com/index.php?page=project_presentation_fr

The page has `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>`

When the page is moved to the production server the charcters are not correctly displayed even when

`<? header('Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8'); ?>`  is added.

http://vps6533.inmotionhosting.com/~hnocor5/surrey/index.php?page=project_presentation_fr

However, if the include is accessed directly the encoding issue disappears:

http://vps6533.inmotionhosting.com/~hnocor5/surrey/project_presentation_fr.php

Any advice on what to do to correct this?

Live HTTP Headers initial block shows the correct encoding.

```
http://vps6533.inmotionhosting.com/~hnocor5/surrey/index.php?page=project_presentation_fr

GET /~hnocor5/surrey/index.php?page=project_presentation_fr HTTP/1.1
Host: vps6533.inmotionhosting.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:9.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/9.0.1
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Connection: keep-alive

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 08 Jan 2012 21:31:28 GMT
Server: Apache
Keep-Alive: timeout=3, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Comment: Maybe it's not `UTF-8` encoded?

Comment: you should check whether your uploaded file header defined UTF-8 or ANSI, if this is ANSI, that may be cause of problem.

Comment: Have the same encoding error on both urls (with Chrome). This is the header you send: <code>HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Date: Sun, 08 Jan 2012 21:45:37 GMT

Server: Apache

Keep-Alive: timeout=3, max=100

Connection: Keep-Alive

Transfer-Encoding: chunked

Content-Type: text/html</code>

Comment: Is the data coming from the same database?Or do you have dev and production databases?

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I'm unclear about the suggestion.  Can you elaborate?

Comment: Firavun, this isn't a forum; comments belong under a question or answer. Unless the text itself you believe significantly answers the question *specifically*, do not post an answer. See the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: If I open either the include or index.php in UltraEdit the encoding it sees is UTF-8.

Comment: @Jared - f I open either the include or index.php in UltraEdit the encoding it sees for the files is UTF-8.

Comment: @MArk - this is just an include file.  The UTF-8 database results from searches on other pages display fine.

Comment: I don't know how UltraEdit works (whether it defaults or detects accurately character sets for a file). I'd suggest it's possible that's a red herring. Did the intern author the content in a Word file? I've seen that before.

Comment: @ceving When you say both URLs do you mean testbed (first link) and production or the index file and the include file (2nd two links)

Comment: i tried to show on notepad++ screen capture: http://yaof.be/encoding.jpg

Comment: How was the include file transferred from the development to the production server? If ftp (or equivalent) was it a binary or an ASCII transfer?

Comment: @Jared AFAIK UltraEdit detects encodings very accurately and offers conversions as well.

Comment: @Mark - initially I moved the whole fieldset via rsync but after the issue arose I also tried SFTP to move file.

Comment: AFAICT, when the browser (FF9 in my case) detects the charset, it gets it right (ISO-8859-1), whereas specifying UTF-8 doesn't. I'm no character encoding expert, but see my answer for an example that (appears) to work.

Comment: Thanks Firavun.  That is the same as what I was saying about UltraEdit.  Jared's solution solved it.  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note, when I change the `charset` to:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
```

It appears to work. Demo:

http://jfcoder.com/test/index.php.htm

Comment: Which means that text, as received by browser is not in utf-8.

Comment: Added a test file with the tag change here; my browsers show no change:  http://vps6533.inmotionhosting.com/~hnocor5/surrey/test.php?page=project_presentation_fr

Comment: @jerrygarciuh - Your PHP header's `content-type` is still `text/html; charset=UTF-8`.

Comment: Ahhh- I had not removed the added PHP header when I made test file.  This does fix it! Thank you.  What was incorrectly done in the file?

Comment: Well, I'm really not an encoding savant, I muddle. But... When I've seen this kind of thing, it's usually because content was authored in some medium (ahem, MS Word) where the encoding is not as expected. I can't tell you specifically, except that if you have a lot of problematic mixing of encodings in source files/records, it can be a real pain to resolve.

Comment: @jerrygarciuh - The key for me was what was *working*, IE, the browser display of the include. Once I checked the *browser's* detected encoding and matched the page's charset with what the browser *suggested* (I don't know, *detected*?), I just tried that with the full page. Start with what works and *compare that to what you have*. Don't force or reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Cool, thanks very much for the help!  I'm not sure if the intern originally composed in Word or some other tool.  She's gone back to France and is much too busy to fix her own messes!  Next time you come to New Orleans I owe you a beer!

Comment: @jerrygarciuh - I would think you'd be better off with that content in UTF-8, but I've not found a really expedient way to do that (Notepad let's you save one character type to another per file... Kinda tedious). I'm sure there is one, though. Encoding is still a third rail for me. If I'm in NO, I'll let you know. `:)` The Saints looked pretty dominate yesterday. Looks like NO v GB is a go, and a great matchup this year.